# Bluetooth cycles between off and "No Bluetooth Found" Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

Bluetooth appears to cycle between "Bluetooth Turned Off" and "No Bluetooth Found", and toggling it on makes no difference, the slider says that it's on, but it still doesn't work.
The only way to stop it is to reboot the computer.

It happens after i just turn off bluetooth after using it, but not right after the reboot, so i can't replicate it immediately, and i have to wait.

Logs say `Bluetooth: hci0: sending initial HCI reset failed (-19)` around a thousand times.
I tried killing/rebooting bluetooth around 5 different ways, even finding bluetooth in htop and manually killing it, but it seems absolutely unfazed, and just keeps printing more and more hci0 errors into the logs.

If i go into the airplane mode, it seems to cycle with the bluetooth.

I tried googling a lot, but this error, it seems, is extremely rare.

I am on the latest version of Ubuntu 22.04, HP Laptop.

I may be missing something obvious, but i have tried everything in my reach.